# Adobe AIR inside a native Android app

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, native

Is it possible to run an AIR application from inside a native Android application?
something like a "WebView" ~ "AIRView"

Comment: When i was at FITC Amsterdam earlier this year, i asked this to the Adobe guys. the answer was nope... dunno have it changed since then or not...

Comment: you can play .swf file from webview if adove flash player supported and installed on device

Comment: So is it possible to lunch an AIR app from within the native app?

Comment: you will be able to run the swf file which will be limited to the capabilities of the flash mobile player. and not air.